# How to Pivot table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that currently looks like what is below. I'd like to only have one row per date and then have each EditType value be a separate column with the count so I can easily view the different types of edits based on the day. Can this be done using a pivot?

[image]

Or... would it be better to back up a step before I've grouped the rows in order to get the counts, like what is shown below?

[image]

The desired output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: There are several `PIVOT` examples. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Google PIVOT in SQL Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Gdb
,   Tbl
,   EditDate
,   [I]
,   [U]
,   [D]
FROM #TABLE
PIVOT (
    COUNT(EditType)
    FOR EditType IN ([U], [I], [D])
) AS PIVOTED
```